# Capture communication between nginx and http clients, and nginx and my application

Tags: tcpdump

My website is hosted on my remote server **REM1**. I access this server through ssh.

My website, which is used by few persons, slows down sometimes and I think it comes from my [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx)'s configuration because when I restart it all works again normally.

I'd like to analyse communication/packets exchanged between http client-[nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) and between [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx)-my application.

When I run this:

```
sudo tcpdump -S -p -A
```

I get millions of packets of ssh, so it's impossible to read http packets among the sea of ssh packets.

When I try to run this:

```
sudo tcpdump -S -p -A port not 22
```

I get nothing even if I open a page of my website on my browser and I refresh many times.

I'm new to [tcpdump](/questions/tagged/tcpdump), and it's really about [tcpdump](/questions/tagged/tcpdump) no matter what web server is used.

How do I capture only nginx communication?